# Why does gprolog not chain together uses of modus ponens?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am reading [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/), *1.1.2 Knowledge Base 2* where they write about chaining together uses of modus ponens.

The KB2.pl file:

```
listensToMusic(mia).
happy(yolanda).
playsAirGuitar(mia) :- listensToMusic(mia).
playsAirGuitar(yolanda) :- listensToMusic(yolanda).
listensToMusic(yolanda) :- happy(yolanda).
```

When the query:

```
playsAirGuitar(yolanda).
```

is submitted to gprolog, it is supposed to respond `yes`, because it should be able to infer it from the fact that yolanda is happy.

But gprolog responds with `no`. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to ["Learn Prolog Now"](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that the problem is that the clauses of the predicate listensToMusic/1 are separated.

the following code returns yes for me:

```
listensToMusic(mia).
listensToMusic(yolanda) :- happy(yolanda).
happy(yolanda).
playsAirGuitar(mia) :- listensToMusic(mia).
playsAirGuitar(yolanda) :- listensToMusic(yolanda).
```

you should get a warning like

```
warning: discontiguous predicate listensToMusic/1 - clause ignored
```